# what is difference between {{}} and {% %} in django templates

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am very new to django and working on it.. I visited a html file and dont know the difference between **{{}}** and **{% %}** in html files used
as here

```
{% load static %}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: [Read the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [{% %} and {{ }} in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625634/and-in-django)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use

- `{% %}` For sentences such as `if` and `for` or to call tags such as `load`, `static`, etc.
- `{{ }}` To render variables in the template.

Read More about it at [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/#variables)

Comment: someone is not feeling cheer in the new year

Answer (score 6):

`{% %}` is for displaying code and `{{}}` is for displaying variables

Answer (score 4):

There are three things in the template in Django
First is template variable and the second thing is template tag and third and last is template filter
so we write a template variable is `{{}}`
and write a template tag is `{% %}`
third and last is template filter `{{variable |filter:arg}}`

Answer (score 2):

I'm new too for Django, so if i'm wrong, please someone correct me.
The difference between they are:

`{{variable}}` is used to use a variables. When the template encounters a variable, it evaluates that variable and replaces it with the result.

You also can use filters `{{variable|filter}}` like this:
`{{name|length}}` in this case you will use a variable "name" and return the length of that variable.

`{%tag%}` could use for loops or logic, or load external information into the template to be used by later variables. You can create block tags to help extend  other html files parts. Also you can create custom tags.

A good place to see how to do it:
https://www.codementor.io/hiteshgarg14/creating-custom-template-tags-in-django-application-58wvmqm5f

Tags like loops and block, need to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

{% %} for **`IF ELSE CONDITIONS`** and FOR LOOP etc

{{ }} for veriables that rendered from view function also used in FOR LOOP veriables like

```
         `enter code here`
{% for obj in qs%}  
    {{ obj.veriable_name }}
{% endfor %}
```